# Joining with mysql going wrong or not giving desired results

Tags: mysql, join

I ran into a little problem which I can't solve myself.

I have a database with 2 tables: `settings` and `verwijzingen`. In the table `verwijzingen` are the data stored that makes a link work. And in `settings` are the navigation and category text with an linked `verwijzing_id` stored.

The problem is: I want to replace the `verwijzing_id` with the actual "verwijzing.waarde" which is the link, I have tried a little bit of JOINING but I  unable to get the desired results.

The queries I tried are:

```
SELECT se.id, se.type, se.text, se.verwijzing_id as link, se.icon FROM settings as se INNER JOIN verwijzingen as ve on se.verwijzing_id=ve.waarde

SELECT s.id,s.type,s.text,s.icon,v.id,v.waarde FROM settings as s INNER JOIN verwijzingen v ON s.verwijzing_id = v.id
```

Comment: Please edit the question and show your attempts.

Comment: how can you find previously tried queries in phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem by using this query:

```
SELECT se.id, se.type, se.text, ve.waarde as link, se.icon FROM settings as se INNER JOIN verwijzingen as ve on se.verwijzing_id=ve.id
```